# ASPxListBox "select all" button

Tags: asp.net, listbox, devexpress

Is it possible to have select all button in listbox? Any ideas how to implement it? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// Set  - SelectionMode="Multiple" for your ListBox and then do

protected void LinkButton1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (ListItem li in ListBox1.Items)
    {
        li.Selected = true;
    }
}
```

Samples are available at:
http://forums.asp.net/t/1241640.aspx/1

and
http://www.aspnet101.com/2008/01/listbox-select-allselect-none/

and
[select all items in the listbox in asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3140258/select-all-items-in-the-listbox-in-asp-net)

Answer (score 0):

You can select all ASPxListBox Items in the following manner:

```
<dx:ASPxListBox ID="lb" runat="server" ClientInstanceName="lbClient" SelectionMode="CheckColumn">
</dx:ASPxListBox>
```

**Client:**

```
lbClient.SelectAll();
```

**Server:**

```
lb.SelectAll();
```